# How I can filter meetings which are going to start in given time range

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working on a specific requirement to filter out any meetings that are going to start in next 15 mins of a given calendar.

I can see that there is `timeMax` query option which will give events starting before given time but the problem I am facing is that I am also getting older events (which are done in past). Any way to get records only froj now to next 15 mins?

I tried query using `syncToken` but I guess that doesnt works with `timeMax` so not able to get just the delta and instead getting all the events.

Comment: there's also a timeMin https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: thanks @train if I understood correctly `timeMin` is used to filter on end time

Comment: looks like it, but I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Calendar Event List API**

As suggested under the comments, you could be using `timeMin` and `timeMax`. It should be something similar to:

timeMin = 2022-12-27T15:30:00+01:00
timeMax = 2022-12-27T15:45:00+01:00

Notes:

- Use the query parameters from above and make sure to respect that it must be `RFC3339` timestamp.

This might be the only available option or suggestion when utilizing the `event.list` to filter them by the 15 minutes mark and check their status. It would be a loop process that could potentially hit a quota.

```js
var request = Calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': calendar_id,
      "singleEvents" : true,
      "orderBy" : "startTime",
      "timeMin":  startDate.toISOString(),
      "timeMax":  maxDate.toISOString()
    });
```

**Calendar API limitation**

If these suggestions or options are not enough or can be considered workarounds due to the limitations, you could always request a feature by going under Issue Tracker.

### References

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)
- [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)